# How to enable/disable communication/power to a USB port on Pi?

Tags: usb

For a Pi 3, what is the correct way to control the power to a USB port?

I am trying using this library, [hub-ctrl.c](https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c). In what folder should the .c file be when I compile it with gcc?

When trying to actually run `sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 3 -P 1 -p 0` I get

```
failed to control. : Invalid argument
```

On a larger scope, is this a correct way to trying to control the USB ports on a Pi 3?

Comment: *"In what folder should the .c file be when I compile it with gcc?"* -> It doesn't matter, obviously you successfully compiled it anyway.  If you hadn't, there would be no `hub-ctrl` executable.

Comment: Does it matter from what folder I run the sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 3 -P 1 -p 0 command?